# DML statement to add multiple accounts in single step

Tags: triggers, apex, dml

I want to add multiple accounts to the salesforce object from the anonymous window. I know how to do that using the below code

```
 Account acc = new Account(Name='account1');
 List<Account> accToAdd = new List<Account>();
 accToAdd.add(acc);
 insert accToAdd;
```

but when I am trying to insert multiple accounts(see code below), it is giving me error as **"Line: 1, Column: 5
Unexpected token '<'."**

```
List<Account> accToAdd = new List<Account>(
 { new Account(Name='triggertest4'),
   new Account(Name='triggertest5'),
   new Account(Name='triggertest3')
 });

insert accToAdd;
```

can anyone help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only brackets in the latter case:

```
List<Account> accToAdd = new List<Account> {
   new Account(Name='triggertest4'),
   new Account(Name='triggertest5'),
   new Account(Name='triggertest3')
};
System.debug(accToAdd);

insert accToAdd;
```

You could also create an empty list, then add the elements, which could be useful in a for-loop:

```
List<Account> accToAdd = new List<Account>();
for (Integer i=3; i<6; i++) {
    accToAdd.add( new Account(Name='triggertest' + i) );
}
System.debug(accToAdd); // |DEBUG|(Account:{Name=triggertest3}, Account:{Name=triggertest4}, Account:{Name=triggertest5})

insert accToAdd;
```

Comment: Thanks, @RubenDG. I see I have an extra '(' in the definition. oops